# Making SQL Server table observable in Rx and C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, system.reactive

I am researching on potential of Rx.NET to stream an sql server data table. Basically I would like to get the data as closer when its inserted as possible without resorting to polling.

I made some POC using Rx/DataReader but I cannot subscribe when new rows are inserted. The stream stopped when there are no more rows to pick (of course this is expected).

Constraints:

- No configuration changes on the SQL Server and databases
- Possibly no polling

I thought of these solutions but those requires license or server changes:

- StreamInsight
- SQLDependency
- Triggers

Is there something like [SQLBrite](https://github.com/square/sqlbrite) in .NET?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Rx turns events, callbacks or tasks into observables - there's nothing native about it accessing databases. If your database has some way of pushing notifications to you then you can turn it into an observable. And you certainly could use polling.

Comment: My goal was find the possibility to get the data close to when it arrive in sql server as possible without making any configuration changes in DB.

I am now looking at possibility of StreamInsight. Based on my initial skimming, this seems possible to use the assemblies directly in .net project.

Comment: A combination of triggers, Sql Server Service Broker, and Rx should be possible. That's an awful lot to write up without you showing some work.

Answer (score 3):

The effort and pain necessary to use Service Broker is huge (Message types, Contracts, Queues, etc), if you're not a SQL Server guy don't even consider.

There's an open source implementation that seems to help. You can check it out: https://tabledependency.codeplex.com - it might be more than you expect to solve your problem.

Simpler than that you can use/play with SqlDependency -  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx In a few lines of code you can watch table changes (with some limitations), just watch out for the app, and database performance.

None of them provide an `IObservable<T>` out of the box. But once you have a `DataChanged`, `OnDependencyChange` event, or something similar. You can abstract that with `Rx`, converting .net events to observables - 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229241(v=vs.103).aspx